# Butter knife is compiled at runtime?

Tags: android, butterknife

I am thinking to use Butter knife for android,It seems very powerful to simplify code

The problem is that I am doing games so the performance and apk size is very important for me

My questions are:

- Butter knife its only used at compile time or it inject views on runtime?
- It cause anyperformance issues?
- Does it use reflection?

Comment: *Instead of slow reflection, code is generated to perform the view look-ups. Calling bind delegates to this generated code that you can see and debug.* This sentence should answer all your three questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ButterKnife` will slow down your performance, but only very slightly. It does inject views at runtime when you call `ButterKnife.bind`. Although I would still recommend using it as the improvement to your code will be worth the minute amount of performance you will loose.

Comment: It shouldn't slow down performance, if anything the app should be a bit more performant because the lookups are already completed for you. I have a suspicion that compile times may suffer.